How to display in RAC "Espèces" with relative_abundance >=0.07 and with relative_abundance >= 0.01?
I was processing this Rank Abundance Curve and I was able to display species with Relative abundance >= 0.05, however, in addition I would like to show species with Relative abundance <= 0.02 but I don't know how to handle it
Here is the code I've used to process this graph:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

attach(xxxx) 

df_xxxx = xxxx %>% 
  group_by(Habitat,Especes) %>%
  summarise(Abundance=sum(Somme_abondance))

df_xxxx <- as.data.frame(df_xxxx)

rank_xxxx <- df_xxxx %>%
  group_by(Habitat) %>%
  mutate(rel_abundance=Abundance/sum(Abundance)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(rel_abundance)) %>%
  mutate(Rank=row_number())

plot_1 <- ggplot(rank_xxxx,aes(x=Rank,y=rel_abundance,color=Habitat))+ 
  geom_line()+ 
  geom_point(size=2,aes(x=Rank,y=rel_abundance,colour=Habitat))+ 
  theme_bw()+ 
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(label=ifelse(rel_abundance >=0.07, as.character(Especes),'')), 
    max.overlaps = getOption("ggrepel.max.overlaps", default = 12))+ 
  theme_bw()+
  ylab("Relative abundance")+xlab("Species rank")+ 
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=16), 
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=16),
    legend.position = "bottom")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#458B00","black"))+ 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#458B00", "black"))+ 
  ggtitle(label = "xxxx","n Disturbed = 52, n Preserved = 56")+ 
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0,size = 16,face = "bold"), 
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0,size = 12))+ 
  ylim(0,0.3)+ 
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=16), 
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=16)
    )+ 
  scale_x_continuous(
    expand = c(0,1),
    sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = NULL,name = NULL), 
    limits = c(0,90),
    breaks = seq(0,90,10)
    )+ 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16), 
        legend.key.size = unit(1,'cm'), 
        legend.key.height = unit(1,'cm'), 
        legend.key.width = unit(1,'cm'), 
        legend.margin = margin(10,10,10,10), 
        legend.box.margin = margin(-10,-10,-10,-10), 
        legend.box.spacing = unit(20,"pt"))

plot_1


We cannot help because we do not have access to your data xxxx. Please use a minimal, reproducible example so you can be assisted.

Thank you for your comments, what I really want to do is how to add double conditions in geom_text_repel. In my code, everything works well, still I don't know how to add the second conditions "relative_abundance <= 0.02" in addition to "relative_abundance >= 0.07"

Have you tried aes(label=ifelse(rel_abundance <= 0.02 | rel_abundance >= 0.07, as.character(Especes),'')),?

Here is one option for adding a second condition to geom_text_repel().
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cty, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 21, fill = 'gray40', alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = ifelse(cty >= 30 | cty <= 10,
                       as.character(manufacturer),
                       ''))) + 
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-06-27 with reprex v2.1.0

Please mark this answer as accepted or useful if you found it helpful.

Thank you so much for your consideration
